# Is throwing inside the circle beneficial for your catch rate?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Pokémon Go, throwing a Nice, Great or even Excellent ball gives you a better catch rate. Because Pokémon Let's go has a similar system to catch Pokémon, is there a same way to improve your chances? If so, what are the multipliers?

Comment: This isn't an answer as I don't know all the info you're asking for, but YES, getting a Nice, Great, or Excellent _definitely_ improves your chances of capture. There's a bit of text that pops up around the first or second gym that says this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the breakdown on the Catch XP Multiplier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341254/what-is-the-breakdown-on-the-catch-xp-multiplier)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question asks about the catch rate, the other about the experience multiplier