# What is the breakdown on the Catch XP Multiplier

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In let's go, you get xp by catching pokemon.

There's load of multipliers; if you do a nice/excellent catch, if you catch the same pokemon few times in a row, etc.

But what is the breakdown of those multipliers? What is more/less important if you want to farm XP quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Good question. Yesterday I was chaining Magikarps and the xp was fluctuating heavily. Usually I get ~500 xp, sometimes only 200, then all of a sudden 3000. Small fluctuations were probably due to a bad throw, but for the 3k I didn't even throw an "Excellent". It was a tiny or huge speciment, though.

Comment: When you're chaining, you get bonus exp for catch combo in multipliers of 10, that would explain the 3k

Comment: @Chippies So every 10th Pokemon combo catch gives extra x10 exp?

Comment: @Ian I don't know the specifics, but my wife was chaining Ponytas for a shiny and every 10 or so catches she would get extra exp and I believe a chaining combo multiplier

Comment: The only thing I've worked out for certain is that the Pokemon's size has a large impact in the multiplier with both tiny and huge producing larger bonuses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made a research in various pages, but there is no actual fully detailed breakdown showing the multipliers.

All I could find was this list on Serebii

> - Combo Bonus
> - Excellent Throw
> - First Throw
> - Great Throw
> - New Pokémon
> - Nice Throw
> - Size Bonus
> - Successful Catch
> - Synchronized Bonus
> - Technique Bonus

[Catch Rewards](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/catchrewards.shtml)

And the multiplier for Catch Combo, also from Serebii

> With Catch Combos, it starts at *1.1, then goes to *1.5 at Catch Combo 11 but then increases by 0.5 for every 10 Catch Combos.

[Catch Combos](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/catchcombo.shtml)

I'll further explain how to achieve those bonuses, since some are not fully detailed in Serebii:

- Combo Bonus: Obtained when being in a catch combo, if it is the second Pokemon from the same species that you catch you will get 0.1x, and will increase to 0.5x at 11, increasing 0.5x every 10 (example: at 21 = 1x, 31 = 1.5x, 41 = 2x and so on). 
  I don't actually know if this has or not a limit, as it's not stated by the site.
- First Throw: When you catch the Pokemon with your first pokeball throw.
- Excellent Throw: Obtained when the middle circle is really small and you throw the ball within it.
- Great Throw: Obtained when the middle circle is small and you throw the ball within it.
- Nice Throw: Obtained when the middle circle is medium size and you throw the ball within it.
- New Pokémon: Obtained when it's the first time you catch a Pokemon, can't be obtained once you have a full Pokedex, including Mew, Meltan and Melmetal
- Size Bonus: Obtained when you get a L or S size Pokemon, it's higher if the Pokemon is XL or XS size
- Successful Catch: This is always given, since you get it when you catch a Pokemon
- Synchronized Bonus: This is obtained when you catch a Pokemon in 2 players mode, and both pokeballs hit at the same time.
- Technique Bonus: Obtained when you use a Joy-Con or Pokeball Plus, can't be obtained when in handheld mode.

After some research in game I found the next multipliers:

> - Combo Bonus: As stated, it increased my multiplier by 0.1 at the 2nd Pokemon of the same species, my longest streak was 95 and it added 4.5x to my multiplier.
> - First Throw: This increased the multiplier by 0.5.
> - Excellent Throw: This increased my multiplier by 1.
> - Great Throw: This increased the multiplier by 0.5.
> - Nice Throw: It increased my multiplier by 0.2.
> - New Pokemon: It increased my multiplier by 0.1.
> - Size Bonus: This one added 0.5 to my multiplier, couldn't find an XL or XS one
> - Successful Catch: This one is given and makes your multiplier 1x
> - Synchronized Bonus: This added 1 to the multiplier
> - Technique Bonus: It added 0.1 to the multiplier, but I was not able to obtain it when using 2 joy-con

Something to be noted, is that when I gained 3 or more bonuses, it gave me extra bonus sometimes, for example (I'll put the supposed value between parentheses):

- Successful+First+Nice = 1.8 (1.7)
- Successful+First+Great = 2.2 (2)
- Successful+First+Excellent = 3 (2.5)

But when I was in a combo I got the following:

- Successful+First+Combo = 1.6 (1.6)
- Successful+Combo+Nice = 1.3 (1.3)
- Successful+Combo+Great = 1.6 (1.6)
- Successful+Combo+Excellent = 2.2 (2.1)

At 4 or more bonuses it always gave some extra multiplier:

- Successful+Synchronized+Combo+Nice = 2 (1.8)
- Successful+Synchronized+Combo+Great = 2.4 (2.1)
- Successful+Synchronized+First+Excellent = 6 (3.5)

So, in conclusion you should prioritize your throws in the next order:

1. Excellent throw
2. Synchronized bonus
3. Combo bonus*
4. First throw
5. Size bonus
6. Great throw (In case you can't get an excellent throw)
7. Nice throw (In case you can't get excellent or great throw)
8. Technique (not obtainable when using 2 joy-con)
9. New Pokemon
10. Successful catch (since this is always given, you don't have to worry about it)

*For combo bonus it's recommended to take it has high as possible, because with a long combo you can get even more experience, also you get better IV Pokemon and more chance at finding a shiny one.

The best Pokemon to combo is Chansey, and the best route is:

> Route 17

And for Post-game

> Cerulean Cave 2nd Floor